# google-cloud-speech - How to give feedback to Google for the transcript in French

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I'm testing the API in French but for instance when I prononce the first name "Jules", i receive the transcript "Jul" which is incorrect.
How can I inform Google to change the transcript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there's no way to give feedback regarding the results of the transcriptions. However, to improve your results, I suggest either using the [SpeechContext phrases](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v1#speechcontext),the [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/best-practices#top_of_page) or do the [troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/support#troubleshooting) steps.

Comment: Appreciate your feedback @F10